# Handling $_FILES['name1'] with increment name

Tags: php, database

my question:

```
<input type="text" name="sample1">
<input type="text" name="sample2">
```

this input add with javascript with limit `10 max = sample10`.

how to handle this with php? like `$_POST['sample$i']`.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
}
```

and if it can be done, `$some$i = $_POST['sample$i']`.

can i insert to db with `'$some1', '$some2'`?

Comment: Better to just use `name="sample[]"` several times, no keys needed, then `$_POST['sample']` will be an array, much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_POST["sample$i"]`. See [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Yeah, you can use `${"some$i"} = $_POST["sample$i"];` but PLEASE, don't. Use an array to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

it's a lot easier to do it this way.  In your form. set this up as:

```
<input type="text" name="sample[]" />
```

and then in your php use an array like so:

```
foreach $_POST['sample'] as $sample {
  echo $sample.'<br/>';

}
```

This way you don't have to be limited to a finite number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Either use $_POST['sample'.$i] or use sample[] as name attribute & iterate over that.